# UT010067: Servlet container does not permit session creation after response was committed

Tags: eclipse, maven, wildfly, jakarta

estoy ejecutando una aplicación maven jakartaee, con servidor wildfly 27+.

Actualmente tengo el siguiente error:

> 21:34:38,456 SEVERE [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.application] (default task-4) Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010067: Servlet container does not permit session creation after response was committed.

Tengo una página login.xhtml, que hace redirección a un index.xhtml luego de crear una sesión. por ahora solo quiero que abra la página index, y nada más. Pero como ven, aparece el error.

Abajo dejo por ahora, la función relacionada (si no, sería mucho código), y el problema ocurre al momento de intentar renderizar la página.

```
public String validarUsuario() {
    String siguientePagina = "";
    mensaje = "";

    if (rutEmpresa.equals("")) {
        mensaje = "Debes ingresar el Rut de la Empresa";
    } else if (idUsuario.equals("")) {
        mensaje = "Debes ingresar el Rut del Usuario";
    } else if (contrasena.equals("")) {
        mensaje = "Debe ingresar la contraseña";
    } else {
        // Validar Rut
        if (!Rut.validarRut(idUsuario)) {
            mensaje = "El rut del Usuario ingresado, no es válido";
        } else if (!Rut.validarRut(rutEmpresa)) {
            mensaje = "El rut de la Empresa ingresada, no es válido.";
        } else {
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuarioTo = new UsuarioTo();
            usuarioTo = usuario.buscaUsuarioLoginTo(idUsuario, contrasena, rutEmpresa);

            if (usuarioTo.getIdUsuario().equals("")) {
                mensaje = "Error al intentar iniciar sesión, por favor verificar datos.";
            } else {
                UsuarioSession usuarioSession = new UsuarioSession();
                sessionTo.setUsuarioTo(usuarioTo);

                usuarioSession.setUsuarioSession(idSession, sessionTo, rutEmpresa);
                siguientePagina = "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
            }
        }
    }
    validarMensaje("");
    return siguientePagina; //llega a este punto sin problemas, y salta el error.
}
```